# Search Site name on Google, my FB page appear top of the site, not the site

Tags: google-search

When I search my `site name` on Google, its first result is my Facebook page which I created. I never built any backlinks to my FB page. This is not a new site, I have purchased it in 2015 and I use the same name for the site as well as the domain (eg: site title `Example Example` and the domain name `exampleexample.com`). This site online since 2015. Earlier there is no such an issue, first I saw this issue in early 2020.

The second result is also not related to my site name (It has only part of my site name). My site appeared on the 3rd result.

90% of the organic search comes to my blog posts, not the home page, and I can't see major traffic loss.

This is not a popular search term. It is a unique name.

Is it something google penalty?